# IVP and Discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am continuing my effort to learn analysis from Thomson Bruckner and Bruckner's book. I ran into an interesting problem relating to Intermediate Value Property (IVP). The problem goes as follows:

Suppse $f$ has IVP on $(a,b)$ and discontinuous at $x_0 \in (a,b)$. Prove that there exists a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{x : f(x) = y\}$ is infinite.

My Proof is as follows:

Since $f$ is not continuous at $x_o$, we take a sequence of $x_i \rightarrow x_0$. We have for all $\forall \delta > 0 \ \exists n > N$  $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$. Let us consider a monotone subsequence of $x_i$. Now let  $k > N, \ x_k < x_{k+1} < \cdots < x_{k+m} \cdots < x_0$ be one such sequence. Let us say $\nexists y_i \in (x_k, x_{k+1}), y_{i+1} \in (x_{k+1}, x_{k+2}) \cdots$ such that $f(y_i) = f(y_{i+1}) = f(y_{i+2}) \cdots $ and $f(x_{k+i}) != f(x_{k+j}), \ i \ne j$. We have, $f$ by IVP, takes on all the values between $(f(x_k), f(x_0))$ since by our assumption $\nexists y_i \in (x_{k}, x_{k+1}) \cdots $ such that $f(y_i) = f(y_{i+1}) = \cdots$ i.e. $(f(x_{k+i}), f(x_{k+i+1}))$ are all mutually disjoint, our choice of $x_k$ ensures that $f(x_k)$ has a montonic sub-sequence and $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists m > M, \ |f(x_m) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. A contradiction.

Now to my QUESTION, is my proof right? It seems right to me. Thanks in advance to your answer.

Comment: This isn't correct: "We have for all $\epsilon > 0 \ \exists \ \delta > 0$ such $x_n - x_0 < \delta$, but $|f(x_n) - f(x_0)| > \epsilon \ \forall n > N$". What if we have for example $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$, and $f(x_0) = 0$? This function has the IVP and is discontinuous at $x_0 = 0$, but if you choose $\epsilon > 2$ then there is no corresponding $\delta$.

Comment: (1) You messed up the definition of "$f$ is not continuous at $x_0$". (2) $x_{i+1} \in (x_{i+1}, x_{i+2})$ is a badly chosen notation. Let's use $y_{i} \in (x_i, x_{i+1})$. (3) It is not clear how $f(y_i) = f(y_{i+1}) = \cdots$, indeed you did not give a proof.

Comment: @Bungo, I have fixed my proof. I understand I had the clauses all messed up for continuity definition but that was really not necessary. The proof as I wrote did not express what I was trying to claim. I have rewritten it could you see if it is right?

Comment: @John Ma I have made changes to my proof, could you look at it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By shifting $f$ horizontally and vertically if necessary, we may assume that $x_0 = 0$ and $f(x_0) = 0$ without changing anything relevant to this problem. (It's not necessary to do this, but it declutters the notation a bit.)

Suppose that $\{x : f(x) = y\}$ is finite for all $y \in \mathbb R$.

Choose any $\epsilon > 0$. There are only finitely many values of $x$ such that $|f(x)| = \epsilon$, and $|f(0)| \neq \epsilon$, so there must be some neighborhood $(-\delta, \delta)$ such that $|f(x)| \neq \epsilon$ for all $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$.

Moreover, there cannot be any $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$ such that $|f(x)| > \epsilon$. (If there were, then by the IVP there would have to be some $x'$ between $0$ and $x$ with $|f(x')| = \epsilon$.)

We must therefore have $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$. But we can find such a $\delta$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, so we just proved that $f$ is continuous at $0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Awesome and thanks. I have corrected my proof from earlier as well. If you could be kind enough to look at it again, that would be awesome.